# Is it possible for one list X to have a higher arithmetic mean than that of list Y but the 80 percentile of X not exceed 70 percentile of Y?

Tags: mean

Is it possible for one list X all positive to have a higher arithmetic mean than that of list Y (all positive) but the 80 percentile of X not exceed 70 percentile of Y?

What's an example?

Comment: The example is very easy to construct, once you realize that list $X$ can be a proper set of the list $Y$.  For example, fix list Y to be $[1, 2, \ldots, 100]$ first, then take list X to be any subset within the interval $(55, 60)$, then it is easy to see this example satisfies your constraint.

Comment: Another easy way to construct examples is to start with lists of four or more elements and make the largest value in $X$ extremely large, keeping the others the same: this will change none of the percentiles below the 80th while arbitrarily increasing the mean.